# Stripe/Stripe.h not found in PaymentViewcontroller.m

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments

Have integrated stripe payment integration gateway to ios project.When the project is build,it throws error stripe/stripe.h not found especially in paymentviewcontroller.m error.

Have added stripe.framework to the project and also added linked libraries related to it .

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to your `Header Search Paths`.
To fix this, do the following steps:

1. Open your xcworkspace in Xcode.
2. Go into the target settings of your app
3. Head over to the "Build Settings" tab
4. Search for "header search paths"
5. Double-click on them and add the following search path: `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Stripe"`
6. You might need to change `non-recursive` to `recursive` as well if it still won't work.